# How to add a link in wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin for WordPress but I can't figure out how to redirect or link to another .php file within the admin panel.

I have a list with items, and a button to redirect to another page that will be settings for this item.

So far I have been trying to accomplish it with this

    `$page = 'vd_booking-Cabin';
    $id = $row->id;
    $record_url = add_query_arg(compact('page', 'id'), admin_url('admin.php')); 
    echo "<td><a href='$record_url'>Change</a></td>";`

But when I click that, it tells me that I don't have enough privileges to access this page.

This is the first time I do anything with wordpress so I might be doing everything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below.

```
admin_url('admin.php?page=xyz');
```

OR

Create menu for particular section.

```
menu_page_url('vd_booking-Cabin');
```